# Getting errors on android studio while trying to run basic activity

Tags: java, android

So I recently started learning app development and the first thing I tried from the tutorial am using is start a new project then I selected basic activity and I did not add anything to any of the files or removed anything so when I tried running the basic activity with its built in code it gives me errors

The errors I got were java.lang.Runtime: 26 issues were found when checking AAR metadata, update this project to CompileSDKVersion 33, and that certain dependencies or classes were repeated and it suggested going to the main android studio page so I clicked the link and I tried to see which solution could help me I luckily updated the compilesdkversion to 33 but the classes and dependencies still are a big issue

Comment: Please share your *build.gradle* files.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Go to gradle task and execute gradle clean and then gradle build command
When you open the android studio for the first time - then sometimes it didn't download multiple dependencies, best way is to execute the above command

Also do ensure to download emulators in case you have not downloaded while installing android studio.
While installing emulators - along with, it download multiple other files, so best way to remove these errors is to install the emulators

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).